# Are we using software to analyze our telescope data?

Tags: telescope, observation, raw-data, analysis

It seems like to me all our analysis of stars and planets could be automated. A computer looks through the data for anomalies and then performs additional observations for that area and then outputs a presumed planet fact sheet based on all its calculations. If it's certainty is less than some threshold, it prompts a scientist to examine the data more closely.

Perhaps this already happens--but from media headlines in the form of "researchers discover another potential habitable planet!" I got the impression that automated detecting wasn't a thing.

I would like to know if we are automating, and if so, how it works (I am particularly interested in the search for Earth-like planets). Otherwise, if we are not automating, I would like to know why we are not.

Comment: Thank you! Anything for planets?

Comment: For exoplanets, there is the [APF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Planet_Finder). For asteroids [NEAT](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_Earth_Asteroid_Tracking) and [LINEAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lincoln_Near-Earth_Asteroid_Research). There are many software in the area, eg [PPAstro](http://www.twesley.com/astro/asteroids.htm).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because off-topic: migrate to Astronomy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is done through APF, NEAT and LINEAR, as mins mentioned however an interesting project currently running is the [Galaxy Zoo](http://www.galaxyzoo.org/), which works on the principle that:

- Humans are much better at identifying certain types of pattern than computers

So while computers trawl raw data for potential points of interest, these are then passed to humans for classification into type, interesting or not, anomalies etc.

As Rikki-Tikki-Tavi commented, [planethunters](http://www.planethunters.org/) does the same for planets.

Comment: I would like to correct: http://www.planethunters.org/ Has been around for a while. There you can look for Exoplanets. It's made by the same people as galaxy zoo.

Comment: excellent - hadn't seen that one. I'll add it in. thanks

Comment: @Rikki-Tikki-Tavi Different teams, tho not surprisingly Chris Lintott (you might know him from BBC's _Sky at Night_ or perhaps _Stargazing Live_ programs) is listed on both. What they share is a common web-based citizen science platform / portal [Zooniverse](https://www.zooniverse.org/). That platform currently hosts [many space related citizen science projects](https://www.zooniverse.org/#space), latest of which was unveiled during this year's _Stargazing Live_ - [Snapshot Supernova](https://stargazing2015.zooniverse.org/#/projects/zooniverse/Snapshot%20Supernova).